# Is a zero dimensional sheaf of length $0$ a zero sheaf on surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a globally generated torsion free sheaf on an algebraic surface $X$(over $\mathbb C$). Also assume that we have an exact sequence of the following form :

$0 \to E \to E^{**} \to T \to 0$

where $T$ is such that $\text{dim}(\text{supp}(T)) =0$(i.e supported on a finite set).

Question : If it's known that,  length$(T) = h^0(T) = 0$,   then can we say  $E \cong E^{**}$? More precisely is it always true that a zero dimensional sheaf of zero length on a surface is always a zero sheaf?

Taking long cohomology sequence  gives us $H^0(E) =H^0(E^{**})$. But I doubt whether $T$ being zero has anything to do with $E$ being globally generated.

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: When you try to prove that $T$ is in fact the zero sheaf, how far do you get?

Comment: @KReiser, I see that all cohomology of that sheaf vanishes but I don't see how to proceed further. That's why I asked the question(may be I am missing something obviuos)

Comment: If the support of $T$ were affine, you would be done, right? You should try to prove this.

Comment: @KReiser,if points of$\text{supp}(T)=\{x_1,...x_n\}$ are distinct(I.e. we are in affine case), then $T$ is perhaps skyscraper sheaf associated to $T(x_1)\oplus....\oplus T(x_n)$ which admits a filtration $0\subset T(x_1) \subset T(x_1)\oplus T(x_2) \subset...T$(?).length of this is zero means at all those points of supports the stalks$T(x_i) =0 $ ,this shows $T=0$.Please correct me if I am wrong. Also what happens if the support is not discrete?

Comment: In the filtration those objects are skyscraper sheaf associated to those objects.

Comment: You should make things simpler for yourself: if the support of $T$ is affine, then $T$ is the zero sheaf because it's global sections are zero, and quasicoherent sheaves on affine schemes are determined by their global sections. The place to use the specific facts about the support of $T$ being zero-dimensional in this case is in proving that the support is affine.

Comment: @KReiser, Is it because discrete zero dimensional subschemes of Noetherian scheme is always affine. Now the question is whether the support is always discrete (may be it is for some trivial reason or otherwise it requires proof)